# If every non-zero vectors be the eigenvector of a real matrix $A$, prove that $A$ is the scalar matrix $\lambda I_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> **If every non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be the eigenvector of a real $n \times n$ matrix $A$ corresponding to a real eigenvalue $\lambda$, prove that $A$ is the scalar matrix $\lambda I_n$.**

I have no idea to start with. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: **Hint:** The matrices $A$ and $\lambda I$ are equal and only if they represent the same linear transformation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$Ax=\lambda x \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \quad \iff \quad (A-\lambda I)x=0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Ok. Its the definition. What will be the next step...

Comment: The second line is *not* simply a matter of definition. The next step is to say if $B=A-\lambda I$ is a matrix such that $Bx=0$ for *every* $x$, then...

Comment: Then its a homogeneous system. It has zero solutions and has non-zero solutions iff $rank(B)<n$. What you actually want to conclude, please.

Comment: Please explore the hints a bit more.

Comment: The hint is that $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ is not a system ( to be solved for some $x$) but an identity that it's true for all vectors.

Comment: @EmilioNovati I am in confusion why $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ is an identity?

Comment: It say that $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ for **all** $x$, and this is possible only if $(A-\lambda I)$ is the null matrix.

Comment: How can you prove the stronger statement: If every nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an eigenvector (but I am not telling you anything about the number of eigenvalues) of $A$, then there exists some scalar $\lambda$ such that $A=\lambda I$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x$ be a non zero vector, $A(x)=\lambda x$, If $y=hx$, $A(y)=A(hx)=hA(x)=h\lambda x=\lambda y$, if $x,y$ are linearly independent,  $A(y)=dy$, $A(x+y)=e(x+y)=A(x)+A(y)=\lambda x+dy$. This implies that $(e-\lambda)x+(e-d)y=0$ since $x,y$ are linearly independent, $e-\lambda=0$ and $e-d=0$, thus $e=\lambda=d$. done.