# Formula for anti-involutive (almost complex structures) and involutive maps on any $V^2$ in terms of linear maps on $V$ based on $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I started studying the book of Daniel Huybrechts, Complex Geometry An Introduction. I tried studying [backwards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme) as much as possible, but I have been stuck on the concepts of [almost complex structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complex_structure) and [complexification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexification). I have studied several books and articles on the matter including ones by [Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/complexification.pdf), [Jordan Bell](https://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/complexification.pdf), [Gregory W. Moore](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/%7Egmoore/618Spring2019/GTLect2-LinearAlgebra-2019.pdf), [Steven Roman](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387728285), [Suetin, Kostrikin and Mainin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2881246834), [Gauthier](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319115108)

I have several questions on the concepts of almost complex structures and complexification. Here is one:

**Some context**: The question below is related to [a question a posted previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537869/bijection-for-involutive-maps-and-mathbb-r-subspaces-given-almost-complex-str).

**Motivation for question below**: From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302358/nice-parameterization-of-linear-complex-structures-on-the-real-plane) or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Complex_planes_in_M(2,_%E2%84%9D)), we get that each almost complex structure $J \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R^2)$ (defined as $J^2 = -id_{\mathbb R^2}$, i.e. $J$ is anti-involutive) is represented, under the group isomorphism $Aut_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R^2) \cong GL(2,\mathbb R)$, by a matrix

$$J \cong \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ \frac{-1-a^2}{b} & -a \end{array} \right], a,b \in \mathbb R, b \ne 0$$

This is because we can write $J \in (End_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R))^{2 \times 2}$ as

$$J = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \hat a & \hat b \\ (-1-\hat a^2)(\hat b)^{-1} & -\hat a \end{array} \right], \hat a,\hat b \in End_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R), \hat b \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R),$$

where $\hat a := a \ id_{\mathbb R}$ is the unique element of $End_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R)$, under the $\mathbb R$-vector space isomorphism $End_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R) \cong \mathbb R$,  that is scalar multiplication by $a$. Likewise for $\hat b$.

Similarly, each $\sigma \in Aut_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R^2)$ that anti-commutes with $J$ (i.e. $\sigma \circ J = - J \circ \sigma$) and is involutive (i.e. $\sigma^2 = id_{\mathbb R^2}$) can be represented, again under $Aut_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R^2) \cong GL(2,\mathbb R)$, by a matrix

$$\sigma \cong \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos(2t) & \sin(2t) \\ \sin(2t) & -\cos(2t)  \end{array} \right], t \in [0,\pi)$$

This is because we can write $\sigma \in (End_{\mathbb R}(\mathbb R))^{2 \times 2}$

$$\sigma = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \hat\cos(2t) & \hat\sin(2t) \\ \hat\sin(2t) & -\hat\cos(2t)  \end{array} \right], t \in [0,\pi)$$

---

### **Question**:

Let $V$ be an $\mathbb R$-vector space, possibly infinite-dimensional. Under the $\mathbb R$-vector space isomorphism $(End_{\mathbb R}(V))^{2 \times 2} \cong End_{\mathbb R}(V^2)$, what are the formulas, in terms of block matrices with elements in $(End_{\mathbb R}(V))^{2 \times 2}$, for almost complex structures $J$ on $V^2$ and for conjugations $\sigma$ on $V^2$ [with respect](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537869/bijection-for-involutive-maps-and-mathbb-r-subspaces-given-almost-complex-str) to canonical $I(v,w):=(-w,v)$ (i.e. I refer to $\sigma^2 = id_{V^2}$ and $\sigma \circ I = - I \circ \sigma$)?

---

Some notes:

1. For example, for canonical $I(v,w):=(-w,v)$, we get $$I = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \hat 0_V & -id_V\\ id_V & \hat 0_V \end{array} \right],$$

where $0_V$ is the zero of $V$ and where $\hat 0_V$ is the zero element of $End_{\mathbb R}(V)$, which is also the constant map, on $V$, with value $0_V$.

2. Guess as to what the answer is not: $$J = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a \ id_V & b \ id_V \\ \frac{-1-a^2}{b} \ id_V & -a \ id_V\end{array} \right], a,b \in \mathbb R, b \ne 0$$ $$ \sigma =\left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos(2t) \ id_V& \sin(2t) \ id_V \\ \sin(2t) \ id_V & -\cos(2t) \ id_V  \end{array} \right], t \in [0,\pi)$$

- I mean that for $J, \sigma \in (End_{\mathbb R}(V))^{2 \times 2}$, I guess the elements are not necessarily going to be 'multiplication by a scalar' or 'scalar multiple of the identity' (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795345/if-every-non-zero-vectors-be-the-eigenvector-of-a-real-matrix-a-prove-that-a) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090362/if-every-vector-is-an-eigenvector-the-operator-must-be-a-scalar-multiple-of-the) for every non-zero is eigenvector; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181761/linear-transformation-t-such-that-ts-st) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/a-linear-operator-commuting-with-all-such-operators-is-a-scalar-multiple-of-the) for commutes with every linear operator - I guess this part is related to [Schur's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma); see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3413082/if-a-commutes-with-both-of-these-matrices-then-a-must-be-a-scalar-multiple-of-t) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154750/if-a-matrix-commutes-with-a-set-of-other-matrices-what-conclusions-can-be-drawn) for commutes with particular matrices)
- 2.1. I think these elements are called '[homothety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma)'.

3. What I tried for $J$:

- 3.1. Solving $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} -id_V & \hat 0_V \\ \hat 0_V & -id_V \end{array} \right], a,b,c,d \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$ appears to just give me $a^2+bc=-id_V$, $ab+bd=\hat 0_V$, $ca+dc=\hat 0_V$, $cb+d^2=-id_V$. I'm stuck on this part. Also, I'm not sure if any 2 of $a,b,c,d$ commute.

  - 3.1.1. Well I guess a and d are 'anti-similar', a term I just made up to mean that a and -d are similar, if b or c is invertible.
  - 3.1.2. Also, in $id_V+a^2+bc=\hat 0_V$, we could have $b=0$ or $c=0$ in which case $a$ is an almost complex structure on $V$ and thus $V$ is infinite-dimensional or even-dimensional.
  - 3.1.3. Then there's [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), according to Omnomnomnom's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3545108/can-matrices-be-similar-or-conjugate-by-nonzero-non-invertible-matrix).
  - 3.1.4. I think the centre of $End_{\mathbb R}V$, which [I think is equal to the subset of the homothety elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/a-linear-operator-commuting-with-all-such-operators-is-a-scalar-multiple-of-the) by [Schur's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma), can be parametrised as done by [luis](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/451164/luis) in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302358/nice-parameterization-of-linear-complex-structures-on-the-real-plane) assuming it makes sense to talk about $e^x$ (e.g. by [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) or by [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory))) for any $x \in End_{\mathbb R}V$ or at least for any $x \in$ the centre of $End_{\mathbb R}V$. I guess that [luis](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/451164/luis)' [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302358/nice-parameterization-of-linear-complex-structures-on-the-real-plane) applies if we can somehow say get that certain exponentials commute even if the underlying maps do not commute.
- 3.2. Also, I'm not sure if it's helpful to use the fact that any almost complex structure $J$ on $V^2$ is similar to the canonical almost complex structure $I$ on $V^2$ (Actually, I'm not sure if this is true for infinite dimensional $V$).

4. What I tried for $\sigma$:

- 4.1. Solving $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{cc} \hat 0_V & -id_V\\ id_V & \hat 0_V \end{array} \right] $$= - \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \hat 0_V & -id_V\\ id_V & \hat 0_V \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right]$ for $a,b,c,d \in End_{\mathbb R}(V)$ appears to give me $c=b$, $d=-a$.
- 4.2. Solving $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ b & -a \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ b & -a \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} id_V & \hat 0_V \\ \hat 0_V & id_V \end{array} \right]$ appears to give me $a^2+b^2=id_V$ and $ab=ba$. I'm stuck on this part unless $(a,b)=(\hat \cos(2t),\hat \sin(2t))$, $t \in [0,\pi)$, in which case I do not know how to justify that $a$ and $b$ are multiplication by a scalar (maybe one of the links in bullet 2 could be helpful).

5. I think every almost complex structure $J$ has $\det J = 1$ (really $1$ and not $\pm1$) and every conjugation $\sigma$ (at least [with respect](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537869/bijection-for-involutive-maps-and-mathbb-r-subspaces-given-almost-complex-str) to canonical $I$; I didn't yet try for arbitrary $J$) has $\det \sigma = -1$ (really $-1$ and not $\pm1$), but I'm not sure how this would help us find $a,b,c,d$. There's probably some rule of determinants of block matrices that's relevant, but I wasn't able to find any on stackexchange or in the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf).
6. Note: For both $J$ and $\sigma$, I first tried with $V = \mathbb R^{n}$, $n \ge 2$, and I got pretty much the same as what I described above for arbitrary $V$.
7. For $V=0$, we have $J=\sigma=id_{V^2}=\hat 0_{V^2} = \hat 0_{V} \oplus \hat 0_{V} = id_{V} \oplus id_{V}$.
8. The $J$ part has been asked about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243214/matrix-representation-of-complex-structures), at least for $V = \mathbb R^n$ (The asker, [Sandro Vitenti](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/55207/sandro-vitenti), has also commented in [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2304256) to an [above linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302358/nice-parameterization-of-linear-complex-structures-on-the-real-plane)).
9. For bullets 3.1 and 4.2, perhaps there is not really a way to simplify this such that there isn't a '[closed-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)' or '[constructive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Discussion)' formula, but I kind of have a feeling there is. At the very least, I'm hoping for a way to represent $J$ by 2 parameters instead of 4 and to represent $\sigma$ by 1 parameter instead of 2.